# Custom Post Type com erro 404

Tags: wordpress

Tenho uma sub página listando alguns Posts Personalizados.

A sub página abre normalmente e lista certinho os posts personalizados, mas quando clico para abrir o post dá página não encontrada.

Registro do Post Personalizado:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_injecao' );
function register_cpt_injecao(){
$labels = array( 
    'name' => 'Cursos de Injeção de Plásticos',
    'singular_name' => 'Curso',
    'add_new' => 'Add Novo',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add Novo Curso',
    'edit_item' => 'Editar Cursos de Injeção de Plásticos',
    'new_item' => 'Novo Cursos de Injeção de Plásticos',
    'view_item' => 'View Curso',
    'search_items' => 'Buscar Cursos de Injeção de Plásticos',
    'not_found' => 'Nenhum Curso encontrado',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nenhum Curso na lixeira',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Curso:',
    'menu_name' => 'Cursos de Injeção de Plásticos',
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "cursos/cursos-de-injecao-de-plasticos"),
    //'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);

register_post_type( 'injecao', $args );
}
```

Se deixo o rewrite setado como **TRUE**, a página **single-injecao.php** abre normal exibindo seu conteúdo, mas ai o que ocorre é que a sub página (cursos/cursos-de-injecao-de-plasticos) dá erro 404...

Alguma solução para esse problema de reescrita da URL? Eu tentei diversas coisas mas quando um funciona o outro dá erro, não sei mais o que fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcelo, de acordo com o [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), na função `register_post_type()`:

> 'slug' => string Customize the permalink structure slug. Defaults to the $post_type value. Should be translatable.

No meu entendimento, isso significa o seguinte:

Por default, o slug do seu custom post vai ser o `$post_type` (no seu caso, `injecao`). Os permalinks funcionam através da definição do `slug`. Com o `rewrite` setado para `false`, você permite que o WP interprete qualquer caminho `/injecao` como um caminho para o seu custom post. Caso você o reescreva (o seu caso), ele ignora o default e força aquilo que você definiu. De acordo com [esta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149191/slug-formatting-acceptable-characters) thread, slugs *não* podem conter caracteres como `/`. O seu 404 provavelmente provém de algum erro relacionado a isto.

Para contornar este problema, juntamente com o conhecido problema dos 404s nos custom posts, existem alguns pontos a se considerar:

1. **Mude o nome do seu Custom Post para `cpt_injecao`**, ou qualquer outro prefixo que você quiser.

   Desta maneira, você evita confusão. O nome `cpt_injecao` será usado apenas para referência a criação do post no seu código. Caso você queira definir uma taxonomia em outro momento, use o nome com o prefixo, de modo que você sabe do que está tratando. Outra vantagem? Você pode
2. **Utilizar a regra de rewrite como `'rewrite' => array("slug" => "injecao")`**. Assim, a palavra `injecao` agora é a referência para o seu custom post tratando-se de permalinks.

   Essa mudança, claro, pode impactar algumas regras de negócio. Não sei como, dentro da estrutura da sua página, você está trabalhando o seu custom post (i.e., Existe uma página com um loop para todos eles? Qual é o nome dessa página?). De acordo com a sua própria pergunta (e de acordo com a conslusão que eu tirei em cima dela), existe uma página chamada *cursos*. Então será que ela vai apresentar o loop de todos os posts, e dentro dela você vai listar os permalinks para o seu hipotético `single-cpt_injecao.php`. Isto pode impactar de tal maneira que talvez seja inteligente você criar um CP novo chamado *cursos* (isso tudo, claro, baseado na minha opinião). É interessante que você reavalie essas regras porquê:
3. **Custom Posts e páginas não podem ter o mesmo nome!!!**

   Em uma acalorada discussão que pode ser acompanhada [aqui](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pages-and-custom-types-cannot-have-the-same-name-so-how-to-structure-permalinks), é possível ver que muita gente já teve esse problema (e gente que ainda tem). Se você cria um CP chamado `books`, e depois uma página chamada `books`, usa a página para listar os CPs e ainda utiliza a estrutura de permalinks, o WP se perde. Ele não sabe o que é post e o que é página, devido ao `rewrite`, e aí, BOOM! 404.

Minha sugestão então: revise, primeiramente, a sua estrutura de páginas, e como elas serão usadas para chamar os seus CPs. Aconselho você a não usar uma página com o mesmo nome do CP, pra evitar o problema citado na discusão. E, por fim, caso você ainda esteja tendo problemas com 404, dê um flush nas suas regras de permalinks. Para fazer isto, basta ir na configuração, salvar ele como qualquer outra coisa e depois voltar para onde estava (provavelmente o seu está setado como 'Nome do Post'). Dessa maneira, você está evitando o temido 404.

Eu já tive esse problema antes, e tive que fazer basicamente o mesmo processo que descrevi aqui. Não fiz nenhum teste, mas acredito que minha resposta vai elucidar bastante o seu trabalho.